# Eagle does not show names correctly

Tags: eaglecad

I used name tags (these little arrow tag forms) a while ago on this schematic, now coming back I haven't got the option to switch on name tags (or at least it doesn't work) and some names are not shown, they are just shown as a D with a strike through.

Any ideas?

[image]

When I rename the net it does show the correct name however in the renaming window. But even if I change it it does not show up in the schematic.

Here is a screenshot of a old document I have of the same schematic part.

[image]

Even with the bad resolution you can clearly see that there are labels with arrows here but they vanished now.

Comment: You have to name the wires. Annotated names will automatically reflect those wire names. For anonymous wires (those starting with N$) the annotated names are not shown IIRC. If you used dports/nports from the library, see there are those with built-in annotations while others are simply an outline to put arbitrary text into.

Comment: The nets are named, the names do show up if I start to rename the nets. They also did show up in the past in the labels but no longer. Also the labels are not shown as arrows anymore. I've found an old screenshot and will edit in a second image now.

Comment: Could it be you simply disabled a certain layer?

Comment: No the labels are shown correctly, just not the name itself just something corrupted. And the arrow shape is not there